# json combobox mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

Hi guys i m try to make a combobox with json but cant do this righ

Jquery function

```
$("select#selest").change(function(){
    $("select#reccid").html('<option value="">Carregando...</option>');
    $.getJSON("/inc/geraCidades.php",{estado: $(this).val()}, function(resposta){
        if(resposta === null){
            var options = '<option value="">-</option>';
        }
        else{
            var options = '<option value="">-</option>';
            $.each(resposta, function(key, val) {
                options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + val + '</option>';
            });
        }
        $("select#reccid").html(options);
    })
})
```

My php file

```
<?
header("Content-Type: application/json");
include("config.php");
$Estado_Id = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["estado"]);
$Sql01 = "SELECT * FROM tabcidades WHERE Estado_Id = '$Estado_Id' ORDER BY Cidade_Nome ASC";
$Query01 = mysql_query($Sql01, $Conn);
while($Rs01 = mysql_fetch_array($Query01)){
    //if($Rs01["Cidade_Id"] == $Cidade_Id) $selected = "selected";
    //else $selected = "";
    $array[] = array('key' => $Rs01['Cidade_Id'], 'val' => $Rs01['Cidade_Nome']);
}
 echo json_encode($array);
```

?>

the return come only object

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is your output of php file?

Comment: [object object]  also if i do  $array[] = array($Rs01['Cidade_Id'], $Rs01['Cidade_Nome']);  returns  like ID, NAME  1,New York  but the select value comes wrong

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code..

```
$("select#selest").change(function(){       
    $("select#reccid").html('<option value="">Carregando...</option>');
    $.getJSON("/inc/geraCidades.php",{estado: $(this).val()}, function(resposta){
        if(resposta === null){
            var options = '<option value="">-</option>';
        }
        else{
            var options = '<option value="">-</option>';                    
            $.each(resposta,function(arrayID,resp){
                $.each(resp,function(key,val){
                    options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + val + '</option>';
                });
            });             
        }
        $("select#reccid").html(options);
    })
})
```

That gives me options in second dropdown including key and value like this 1Test

and I have asked for php output i.e. value of $array in php file. Have a look the $array value which prints two dimensional array, so you need to loop two times to set option. Hope this will help you.